# Multiple representations of the same entity in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I use `JBoss EAP 6.3` and `Hibernate 4.2.14.SP4-redhat-1` and I get error like that:

```
14:07:36,107 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-3) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component ServicesDfeContract03DAOImpl for method public abstract pl.com.adh.jleo.core.datamodel.datachecker.DataCheckerDTO pl.com.adh.jleo.weblsp.dao.operations.dfecontract03.pub.IServicesDfeContract03DAO.finalize(pl.com.adh.jleo.weblsp.ob.base.IDataModel) throws java.lang.Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [pl.com.adh.jleo.core.ob.dfecontract.DfeContractAttributeOB#3948] are being merged. Detached: [pl.com.adh.jleo.core.ob.dfecontract.DfeContractAttributeOB@f6c]; Detached: [pl.com.adh.jleo.core.ob.dfecontract.DfeContractAttributeOB@f6c]
...
```

I read that it is issue associated with `Hibernate 4.2.14.SP4-redhat-1` version. In which version this bug is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The bug was fixed in Hibernate 4.2.15 and 4.3.6 and above.

Refrence https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9106